# IMPORTRANGE in google sheets not coping data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Adding permission it still shows loading signal, with #REF! in the selected column. Attempted all possible methods as per this following link.

```
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75943?authuser=0
```

```
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340
```

It's possible to copy value from a sheet when the visibility had changed to "Anyone on the internet with this link can view" in sharing.

But, wish to copy value from one sheet to another without changing the visibility in sharing.

Comment: Have you enough free space to import data? Please give more details and a copy of your spreadsheet!

Comment: possible to copy value from one sheet to another without changing the visibility in sharing ?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet